# Looping Over a Java Object and Passing One Field to a Mongo Query Similar to SQL WHERE...IN Clause

Tags: mongodb, mariadb, java

I am trying to construct a MongoDB equivalent of an SQL WHERE IN clause by iterating over a Java Object List and using one field in that list to fill in the IN data. Using generic example, I would like to build the following command in MongoDB syntax:

```
SELECT title FROM albums WHERE recorded_year IN ('1967','1968','1969','1970');
```

The SQL command IN data is extracted from the Album object recordedYear value using the following loop:

```
if (albums.size() <= 1000) {
    sb.append("SELECT title FROM albums WHERE recorded_year");
    sb.append(" IN (");
    for (int i = 0; i < albums.size(); i++) {
        sb.append("'");
        sb.append(albums.get(i).getRecordedYear());
        sb.append("'");
        if (i < albums.size() - 1) {
            sb.append(",");
        } else {
            sb.append(")");
        }
    }
}
```

Most Mongo/Java sites I visited seem to deal with command structures using hard-coded values which, while helpful, is completely impractical in real world applications. Any help in pointing to a good tutorial, or if someone has the actual code itself would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: To access MogoDB database from a Java application you have to use a driver software: [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did have the driver installed and can make a MongoClient object, a MongoDatabase object, and a MongoCollection object where I can getAllDocuments. But the issue I am having is understanding how to pass a Java Object list to the to the getAllDocuments. So essentially the command would be something like "getAllDocuments WHERE document id in (Java Object[0].recorded_year, Java Object[1].recorded_year, ..., Java Object[n].recorded_year)"

Answer (score 0):

> But the issue I am having is understanding how to pass a Java Object
>   list to the to the getAllDocuments...

Make an array of elements which you want to match with the field using the `in` operator. For example, If you have a `someObject.year` field, then the array will have the year values; `int [] matchYears = { 1989, 2001, 2012 }`. Instead of an array you can also use a `List` collection.

The query:

```
Bson queryFilter = in("recordedYear", matchYears);
List<Document> result = new ArrayList<>();
collection.find(queryFilter).into(result);
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `queryFilter` is built using the [com.mongodb.client.model.Filters](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) factory class.

The MongoDB documentation on using the [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values).

NOTE: The `int [] matchYears = { 1989, 2001, 2012 }` can be also be created as 
`int [] matchYears = { javaObject1.recorded_year, javaObject2.recorded_year, ... }`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll be taking a look at it in more depth shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite implement it with BSON, but the logic in the method appears to be working with the code below. Thank you again for your help.

```
public void getAlbumYears(MongoCollection<Document> collection, List<Album> albums) {

    BasicDBObject inQuery = new BasicDBObject();

    List<String> year = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Album album : albums) {
        year.add(album.getYear());
    }

    inQuery.put("year", new BasicDBObject("$in", year));

    for (Document document : collection.find(inQuery)) {
        System.out.println(document.toJson());
    }
}
```